# The onenote API handwriting image overlay？

Tags: image, api, onenote, handwriting, inkml

I use C# to call OneNote API, and I have the following problem: After submitting a picture and InkML data, the picture will cover handwriting. There is no way to freely specify the overlap of pictures and handwriting. How can this be achieved.

[image]

This is the effect I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the rasterOp property to copyPen. This is a blog reference for writing ink to OneNote: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/07/onenote-ink-beta-apis/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but my rasterOp has set up copyPen, that blog is not very helpful to me. The content of blog is not involved in the overlapping of many elements, but thank you.